# how Generate QR Code with complex data like contact information?

Tags: ios, iphone, qr-code

Now I generate QR Code with simple text and for that I use below demo project.
    [IOS_QR_Code_Generator](https://github.com/kuapay/iOS-QR-Code-Generator)

And for generating QR code:

```
 NSString *code = @"JAY RAPARKA SIMPLE Encoding string";

 Barcode *barcode = [[Barcode alloc] init];

 self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

 [barcode setupQRCode:code];
 ivQRCode.image = barcode.qRBarcode;
```

Right now I just encode **"JAY RAPARKA SIMPLE Encoding string"** this simple text but I want to generate QR code for more complex data like (Contect information, link/URL, account balance on the base of id,etc..). So please any one done this earlier than please help me.

Thank you!

For decoding I use ZBar sdk and it also works properly and encoding also work but I just want to generate QR for more data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create contact information by giving text in bellow format

```
BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:2.1
N:;Company Name
FN:Company Name
ORG:Company Name
TEL;WORK;VOICE;PREF:+16045551212
TEL;WORK;FAX:+16045551213
ADR;WORK;POSTAL;PARCEL;DOM;PREF:;;123 main street;vancouver;bc;v0v0v0;canada
EMAIL;INTERNET;PREF:user@example.com
URL;WORK;PREF:http://www.example.com/
NOTE:http://www.example.com/
CATEGORIES:BUSINESS,WORK
UID:A64440FC-6545-11E0-B7A1-3214E0D72085
REV:20110412165200
END:VCARD
```

Comment: this idea is cool but in ios we can not create VCARD like this.so i can't accept your answer.sorry!

Answer (score 0):

**You can use this code**

```
- (NSString *)vCardRepresentation
{
  NSMutableArray *mutableArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

  [mutableArray addObject:@"BEGIN:VCARD"];
  [mutableArray addObject:@"VERSION:3.0"];

  [mutableArray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"FN:%@", self.name]];

  [mutableArray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"ADR:;;%@",
                       [self addressWithSeparator:@";"]]];

  if (self.phone != nil)
  {
    [mutableArray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"TEL:%@", self.phone]];
  }

  [mutableArray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"GEO:%g;%g",
                       self.latitudeValue, self.longitudeValue]];

  [mutableArray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"URL:http://%@",
                       self.website]];

  [mutableArray addObject:@"END:VCARD"];

  NSString *string = [mutableArray componentsJoinedByString:@"\n"];

  [mutableArray release];

  return string;
}
```

**OR you can generate String with saparator** 
like,

```
NSString *str = "Name : Jay, Work : IOSDeveloper";
```

and after that saperate this using

NSArray *ary = [mystring componentsSeparatedByString:@","];

now you can use this ary with index.